# Windows form application clicking an "onclick=return"

Tags: c#

So im trying to make an script that does the BFH (in a game) auto but when it clicks on the sumbit button the webbrowser opens up an confirm box (code element inspecting showed down). So how do i make it so my application clicks the ok on the confirm box

The webbrowser opens up a box and the application has to click the ok button

Sorry if i explain it strange its because my english isnt that great

this is the button it clicks

```
<input class="submit" type="submit"
       onclick="return verifyTransport('Are you sure you want to transport €…,000 to the team deposit?\nThe trip will take 25 minutes.');"
       value="Transport € 5,000,000"
       name="dr_transport_money"></input>
```

Example of what it shows(cant show the real one can only do that once a day):

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you are doing **Windows Form Application***? And you want to show `MessageBox`?

Comment: No webBrowser itself opens a box when i click the button but i need the app to click like the ok button

Comment: ohh do you want to automate that action using winforms?

Comment: Yes its an "bot" for a browser game, i got it to work perfectly untill i noticed i didnt know how to make it close this box showed in the picture above

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
private IWebElement element;
element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='dr_transport_money']"));
element.Submit();

driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```